# What's the significance of the envelope found by the girl?

Tags: 10-cloverfield-lane

When the girl in *10 Cloverfield Lane* went upstairs to do a repair she came across a letter that appeared to be from a Japanese company. What did that have to do with the story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an easter egg.

[image]

That company is part of the original Cloverfield movie. The company is the one that drills and releases/awakes the Cloverfield monster. The main character was also leaving to work/live in Japan.

The letter has no affect on the plot for 10 Cloverfield Lane. The two movies exist in a parallel dimension of each other, like any number of anthologies (Twilight Zone, Outer Limits, etc).

Comment: @brettfromla no, it does not. Lane takes place post 2014. Cloverfield in 2008. And Abrams explicitly called it like a Twilight Zone idea. And the director says it's in a different timeline.